# Listile list above textformfield

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I am creating simple listtile list. Widget are placed like: Scaffold -> Padding -> Column -> TextFormField, SizedBox, (Expanded -> ListView.separated(children are listtile)), Container.
But when I am scrolling this kind of image appears:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqOHe.png)

Yes, texts are disappearing under search field, but list tiles are above search field.

List tiles should be disappeared like texts, no?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: sample page you can see from [dartpad link](https://dartpad.dev/?id=1d6051367bcf13114e040311d67e2d2c)

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code it might be helpful for you.

```
body: Column(
    children: [
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
              ),
              hintText: 'Search here...'),
        ),
      ),
      SizedBox(height: 15),
      Expanded(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 15,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              context.read<HomeBloc>().add(HomeItemClickEvent());
            },
            child: Container(
              //height: 55,
              width: double.infinity,
              margin:
                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15, vertical: 5),
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2),
              ),
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text('Title'),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```